# Making a employee contact sheet with pictures and I need to make it responsive

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Using css grid and want to make it responsive for mobile. It has text and pictures and a header on (1) of every row making it (to me anyway) a bit tricky.

Tried different displays and overflow rules

```
<wrapper class="grid">
      <h4 class="departmentOne">Sales Department</h4>
      <div class="one">
        <img class="imageBox" src="./images/abdulplaceholder_1.jpeg" />
        <ul>
          <li>Abdul</li>
          <li>Sales Director</li>
          <li>555-5551</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
        <img class="imageBox" src="./images/davidplaceholder_1.jpeg" />
        <ul>
          <li>David</li>
          <li>Sales Associate</li>
          <li>555-5552</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h4 class="departmentTwo">Service Department</h4>
      <div class="three">
        <img class="imageBox" src="./images/angieplaceholder_1.jpeg" />
        <ul>
          <li>Angie</li>
          <li>Service Director</li>
          <li>555-5553</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="four">
        <img class="imageBox" src="./images/mattplaceholder_1.jpeg" />
        <ul>
          <li>Matt</li>
          <li>Service Advisor</li>
          <li>555-5554</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h4 class="departmentThree">Sales Department</h4>
      <div class="five">
        <img class="imageBox" src="./images/chrisplaceholder_1.jpeg" />
        <ul>
          <li>Chris</li>
          <li>Parts Director</li>
          <li>555-5555</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="six">
        <img class="imageBox" src="./images/seanplaceholder_1.jpg" />
        <ul>
          <li>Sean</li>
          <li>Parts Associate</li>
          <li>555-5556</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="seven">
        <img class="imageBox" src="./images/jimplaceholder_1.jpeg" />
        <ul>
          <li>Jim</li>
          <li>Parts Associate</li>
          <li>555-5557</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h4 class="departmentFour">Sales Department</h4>
      <div class="eight">
        <img class="imageBox" src="./images/debbieplaceholder_1.jpeg" />
        <ul>
          <li>Debbie</li>
          <li>Finance Director</li>
          <li>555-5558</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </wrapper>
```

CSS

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-auto-rows: minmax(125px, auto); */
  grid-auto-columns: repeat(auto-fir, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: .5rem;
  overflow: auto;
}
.row {
  width: 290px;
}
.one {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}
.two {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}
.three {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  padding: 5px;
}
.four {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
  padding: 5px;
}
.five {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
  padding: 5px;
}
.six {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  padding: 5px;
}
.seven {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 3;
  padding: 5px;
}
.eight {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4;
  padding: 5px;
}
.departmentOne {
  padding: 20px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.departmentTwo {
  padding: 20px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.departmentThree {
  padding: 20px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 3;
}
.departmentFour {
  padding: 20px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 4;
}
```

There are no errors but it doesn't look the way I want it. Prefer it to go to one column if needed, but instead it changes to horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have invalid *auto-fit* rule - use `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr))` instead of `grid-auto-columns`.

> Prefer it to go to one column if needed, but instead it changes to horizontal scrolling.

The main issue here is that you are explicitly *placing* all the divs using `grid-row` and `grid-column` definitions, so even though you are using *auto-fit*, these columns may not change at all and you'll lose responsiveness.

Only the `h4` needs to be *placed* in the first column using `grid-column: 1`- see demo below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: .5rem;
  overflow: auto;
}
wrapper > div {
  padding: 5px;
}
wrapper > h4 {
  padding: 20px;
  grid-column: 1;
}
```

```html
<wrapper class="grid">
      <h4 class="departmentOne">Sales Department</h4>
      <div class="one">
        <img class="imageBox" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
        <ul>
          <li>Abdul</li>
          <li>Sales Director</li>
          <li>555-5551</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
        <img class="imageBox" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
        <ul>
          <li>David</li>
          <li>Sales Associate</li>
          <li>555-5552</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h4 class="departmentTwo">Service Department</h4>
      <div class="three">
        <img class="imageBox" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
        <ul>
          <li>Angie</li>
          <li>Service Director</li>
          <li>555-5553</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="four">
        <img class="imageBox" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
        <ul>
          <li>Matt</li>
          <li>Service Advisor</li>
          <li>555-5554</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h4 class="departmentThree">Sales Department</h4>
      <div class="five">
        <img class="imageBox" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
        <ul>
          <li>Chris</li>
          <li>Parts Director</li>
          <li>555-5555</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="six">
        <img class="imageBox" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
        <ul>
          <li>Sean</li>
          <li>Parts Associate</li>
          <li>555-5556</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="seven">
        <img class="imageBox" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
        <ul>
          <li>Jim</li>
          <li>Parts Associate</li>
          <li>555-5557</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h4 class="departmentFour">Sales Department</h4>
      <div class="eight">
        <img class="imageBox" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
        <ul>
          <li>Debbie</li>
          <li>Finance Director</li>
          <li>555-5558</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </wrapper>
```

Comment: Thank you! I finally had a chance to play with it a bit and I see what you mean. I wrote it out hypocritically and your solution helped. I had to make some adjustments naturally but it has but me on right track and mindset.